# How do I use the Dominion & Dominion Intrigue Update Packs?

Tags: dominion, dominion-intrigue

I purchased the Dominion Update Pack (and the one for Intrigue), but it didn't come with any instructions. There is a new slip that is obviously deaigned to go in the center of the original box, replacing the old one. But there are a two strange things about it:

- Several cards in the original are missing from the new strip (e.g. Secret Chamber, Coppersmith)
- The Treasure, Curse, and Victory card slots are blank, whereas they had names in the original

[image]

Are the old cards not supposed to be used if I am "upgrating" by adding the new second edition cards? And what do I do with the card slots that are blank?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The update pack serves two purposes:

1. Replace 6 old cards with 7 newer ones
2. Provide a new card strip; base cards are missing from the new strip.

---

**Replacing older cards**

The following 12 cards have been **removed** from their respective versions:

1. Base game (6): Adventurer, Chancellor, Feast, Thief, Spy, Woodcutter
2. Intrigue (6): Coppersmith, Great Hall, Saboteur, Scout, Secret Chamber, Tribute

You should not use these cards anymore. Naturally, it's your game so you are free to do whatever you feel best, add these together with the rest or not. If you do, however, there might not be enough space in the box to store them, if you keep the base cards in the same box as well. They are not "broken" or "overpowered", just very weak. Usually these cards were skipped, that's why they were removed. *Dominion* creator Donald X. [has explained why each card was removed](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=16338.0).

Should you take them out, remember to remove their respective randomizer (blue-back) cards as well.

---

**New card strip**

Naturally, since 6 kingdom cards have been replaced with 7 new kingdom cards, a new insert has been provided. Therefore, you will not see removed cards listed, such as **Secret Chamber**. You will see the new cards, though, such as **Diplomat**.

- Other cards: you should be able to find all other non-replaced cards on the card strip, such as *Wishing Well*.
- **Base cards**: base cards, such as Curse, Copper, Gold and Province, have been deliberately omitted from the new card strip. This is because the newer [Dominion: Intrigue (second version)](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/209419/dominion-intrigue-second-edition) is **no longer a stand-alone expansion** of Dominion, thus you need the base cards to play it. This means that the whole expansion is not shipped with the base cards, thus they have been omitted from the card strip. Nevertheless, the actual insert should have enough space for you to store them (give or take one slot, as there are 26 kingdom cards now).
- **Empty strips**: you can use them to hold extra cards, such as the base cards or the removed cards.

Comment: Out of curiosity, will there be any problems with playing the removed cards, aside from the difficulty storing them? Are they unbalanced with the new cards?

Comment: @Thunderforge All the cards that were removed were done because they were very weak, or boring; to the point where experienced players very rarely would ever purchase one in a game. Having cards that were not worth buying the majority of the time made the experience worse for new players; so Donald X decided that it would be better if they were replaced.

Comment: @Thunderforge You can read Donald's thoughts on each of the removed cards and why they were removed here: http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=16338.0

Comment: @Thunderforge Thank you for the heads up, I updated my answer to reflect the "*Wishing Well*" issue. Also, as I have written, you can use the blank strips to store the base cards and some thoughts on the removed cards; they are not broken, just very weak.

Answer (score 3):

The update packs are meant to replace cards from the original sets.  No more Chancellor, Adventurer, etc., as these cards were generally under played.  Of course you are free to mix and match whatever you will from the update and the original sets, but that is the intent.  You should continue using the treasure cards and victory cards even though they aren't explicitly printed on the center sheet.